# can't delete unknown files (big size 33 Gb), the filename ,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows

I don't know where I got them from on my USB hard drive.

I'm not expert, but I tried some stuff and still can't delete them.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Something about:

```
The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Any help?
In simple steps please

Comment: It looks like the file system got seriously corrupted: files and folders have gibberish names and random time stamps (mostly in the future). If you don't care about the data you might simply format the drive. That won't help if it's a hardware issue, though. Some troubleshooting steps you can try: 1. Plug the drive to different USB ports, 2. Plug the drive in a different computer, 3. Use a different operating system (e.g. any Linux distribution).

Comment: i care about data ,so last thing will be format the drive ,,,, any another way ?

Comment: in linux, use a recursive wildcard rm.... `rm -r qqq`, or, to remove possible prompting for each file, `rm -rf qqq`.   linux doesn't care about exact names with a recursive rm request.  Perhaps `deltree` in windows?

Comment: @ssd For starters, follow the troubleshooting steps in my previous comment and report back.

Comment: steps 1 and 2 not working , about step 3 i don't have knowledge in Linux , same to use rm -r , i have [backtrack 5 R3]  but i don't know how to use it well :(

Comment: @lornix i tried it on [backtrack 5 R3] (i don't know if that right) but i think it doesn't work too rm -r and rm -rf it said [read-only file system] here screenshot : http://im75.gulfup.com/c5Fr3G.jpg

Comment: But that's a different error, and fixable by remounting the partition rw vs ro.  Perhaps search SU/SO for 'mount ntfs partition in linux'.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with something similar in the past. Here's what I did:

1. Run a `chkdsk` at boot, to prevent issues with your filesystems later in the process.
2. Download and run a Linux Live CD or USB, you can use the [GParted](http://gparted.org) Live Disc, it's small and it's almost all you'll need.
3. Once booted into it, open the file manager, locate your drive and locate your directory.
4. Select it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to completely remove it.

Alternatively, if you want to completely format your partition:

1. Once booting into the GParted Live Disc, open the GParted app (if it isn't open automatically).
2. Locate your drive in the dropdown list at top right corner, it should automatically be selected if it's the only drive.
3. Locate the partition you want to format, right click it and move to the *Format as* menu and select the desired filesystem on the submenu, most commonly `NTFS`.
4. It'd warn you about data loss, but you already know this.
5. Wait until the process finishes and you will have a new, clean partition.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `rd` command.

From the command prompt (cmd.exe), try: `rd /s /q H:\qqq`

The `/s` removes files as well as directories and the `/q` is for quiet mode.

Answer (score 0):

How to delete them follow this steps:

1- eject your USB hard drive

2- press <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> and **HOLD**

3- connect your USB hard drive while holding <kbd>left-shift</kbd>

4- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to switch to address bar

5- type USB hard drive, letter (ex: H: or G:)

6- run this as quickly: drop <kbd>left-shift</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Hold <kbd>left-shift</kbd> again

7- now right-click on `qqq` folder and select Delete option while you are  holding <kbd>left-shift</kbd>

8- after completely delete eject USB Hard drive and connect again.

9- finish. oh, I have to say you can drop <kbd>left-shift</kbd> now.